# I wanted to make my canvas into portrait mode in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I already click on File -> Build Settings -> and switch to android platform since I'm developing a android game using unity, but unfortunately I wanted to it in portrait mode, can anyone help me? I'm new to unity ..

Answer (score 4):

Look at the **Game** Window. You will find a drop-down button at the top-left corner of the window.

[image]

Click on the little "Plus" symbol and you will be able to add the desired format / resolution.

Comment: he will also need to set the orientation to portrait only on the Player settings

Answer (score 3):

Current versions of Unity show individual resolution options, depending on your Player Settings!

(Go from Android to PC build, and you will get other options)